# Gray out items dynamically in ExpandableListview Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am working to create ExpandableListview which has customAdapter derived from BaseExpandableListAdapter. I would like to gray out few child items in the expandable listview on subsequent request

return isChildSelectable = false, doesn't help since I need to grey out the options on subsequent request.

notifyDataSetChanged does not the view as well.

what would be best way to implement it?

Thanks a lot!!

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

static class ViewHolder{
    public CheckBox checkBox;
}

private Context mContext;

 private List<String> mListDataHeader; // header titles
    private Map<String, List<String>> mListDataChild;


    private Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Boolean>> mCheckState = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer,Boolean>>();

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, Map<String, List<String>> listChildData) {



    this.mContext = context;    

    this.mListDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this.mListDataChild = listChildData;
}



@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
      return this.mListDataHeader.size();
}



@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {        
      return this.mListDataChild.get(this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();                       
}



@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}



@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
     return this.mListDataChild.get(this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);

}



@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}



@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
     return childPosition;
}



@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}


public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    return convertView;
}



@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 return convert view;
}



@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create a new List or a SparseArray where you hold each group's children state (gray/not-gray):

```
public SparseArray<List> grayChildren = new SparseArray<List>();
```

Initialize that array in your constructor or whenever the some specific group is expanded.

Modify your `isChildSelectable` to something like:

```
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    if (grayChildren.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now when you need to gray out some item call:

```
mAdapter.grayChildren.get(groupPos).set(childPos, true);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```